# OR Tool pickup delivery problem not working with importing distance matrix from database

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, import, or-tools, vehicle-routing

I am using Google OR Tools for solving the capacitated vehicle routing problem with pickups and deliveries. I am importing distance matrix from psql database and have ensured that it is an integer list. Even then I am getting the following error-

> WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
>   F0618 10:57:31.900391  8448 routing.cc:1554] Check failed: delivery < size (34359738369 vs. 13) 
>   *** Check failure stack trace: ***
>   Aborted (core dumped)

Can someone please help me with it?

This is the pickup delivery version of my code (without demands) for reference-

```
 """Simple Pickup Delivery Problem (PDP)."""
#from __future__ import print_function
import import_data_pd as idp
from ortools.constraint_solver import routing_enums_pb2
from ortools.constraint_solver import pywrapcp

dat = idp.var()
dd=[]

for i in range(10):
    row=[]
    for j in range(10):
        print("dat i j={}".format(dat[i][j]))
        row.append(dat[i][j])
    dd.append(row)
print(type(dd[0][1]))

print("dd={}".format(dd))
# prind output of dd is [[0, 0, 13, 2147, 39, 84666, 84666, 20, 21, 1987], [12, 0, 12, 2160, 39, 84666, 84666, 33, 33, 1999], [42, 29, 0, 2176, 68, 84695, 84695, 49, 49, 2015], [45, 46, 58, 0, 6, 84712, 84712, 66, 67, 2032], [39, 39, 52, 2186, 0, 84705, 84705, 59, 60, 2026], [73, 74, 86, 2221, 34, 0, 0, 94, 94, 2060], [73, 74, 86, 2221, 34, 0, 0, 94, 94, 2060], [34, 22, 33, 2126, 61, 84687, 84687, 0, 0, 1966], [33, 21, 32, 2167, 60, 84686, 84686, 40, 0, 2007], [75, 63, 74, 160, 102, 84728, 84728, 82, 41, 0]]

def create_data_model():
    """Stores the data for the problem."""
    data = {}
    data['distance_matrix'] = dd
    data['pickups_deliveries'] = [[1, 6], [2, 10], [4, 3], [5, 9], [7, 8], [15, 11], [13, 12], [16, 14]]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 4
    data['depot'] = 0
    return data


def print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution):
    """Prints solution on console."""
    total_distance = 0
    for vehicle_id in range(data['num_vehicles']):
        index = routing.Start(vehicle_id)
        plan_output = 'Route for vehicle {}:\n'.format(vehicle_id)
        route_distance = 0
        while not routing.IsEnd(index):
            plan_output += ' {} -> '.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
            previous_index = index
            index = solution.Value(routing.NextVar(index))
            route_distance += routing.GetArcCostForVehicle(
                previous_index, index, vehicle_id)
        plan_output += '{}\n'.format(manager.IndexToNode(index))
        plan_output += 'Distance of the route: {}m\n'.format(route_distance)
        print(plan_output)
        total_distance += route_distance
    print('Total Distance of all routes: {}m'.format(total_distance))


def main():
    """Entry point of the program."""
    # Instantiate the data problem.
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the routing index manager.
    manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(data['distance_matrix']),
                                           data['num_vehicles'], data['depot'])

    # Create Routing Model.
    routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)


    # Define cost of each arc.
    def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
        """Returns the manhattan distance between the two nodes."""
        # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

    transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
    routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

    # Add Distance constraint.
    dimension_name = 'Distance'
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        0,  # no slack
        3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
        True,  # start cumul to zero
        dimension_name)
    distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
    distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

    # Define Transportation Requests.
    for request in data['pickups_deliveries']:
        pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[0])
        delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(request[1])
        routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
        routing.solver().Add(
            routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(
                delivery_index))
        routing.solver().Add(
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <=
            distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index))

    # Setting first solution heuristic.
    search_parameters =  pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
    search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
        routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION)

    # Solve the problem.
    solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)

    # Print solution on console.
    if solution:
        print_solution(data, manager, routing, solution)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you distance matrix is 9x9, and some of your pdp pairs are [15, 11], [13, 12], and [16, 14].

Furthermore, you have distances in the 80k, and the max capacity of your dimension is 3k. 
So the problem is infeasible.